# connect flutter to python

Tags: python, android, flutter, figma

I'm making an android app with Flutter and Python but I don't know how to connect my frontend (flutter) to my backend (python), So can any one helps me?

(If it be a YT video is better)

I made UI with Figma, converted that to flutter, I wrote python backend.
how I can connect them together?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you should write POST, GET, etc. APIs in Python. Then you need to connect these APIs to Flutter via http or dio or other packages by Flutter. Since I don't have video material, you can watch what I wrote on youtube and other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You should add CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations to your backend (if you don't). Then you need to **publish it** anywhere you want (you can publish [here](https://heroku.com), for example). Then you can fetch your **Backend API** through **HTTP requests** from your **Flutter app**. Here is [tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data) from Flutter docs.